# python packages to remove badwords

Tags: python, package

IS there any package in python that can do sentimental analysis like removing Bad words and curse words.
I am using text blob and doing sentimental analysis by taking the polarity score. But, I need a package to filter or remove the bad word.

Comment: [prodigy](https://prodi.gy/) has a good tutorial for this (related to [spacy](https://spacy.io/))

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is but I found this: [What's a good Python profanity filter library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3533322/6635590)

Answer (score 0):

the better_profanity package can remove curse words in addition to alternate spellings of those words using. Here is a [link](https://pypi.org/project/better-profanity)

to install it use:

```
pip install better_profanity
```

It doesn't do sentiment analysis, but there are packages like nltk (VADER) that do that. Here is a [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5269445/Using-Pre-trained-VADER-Models-for-NLTK-Sentiment)